# Filter DataGrid for name with TextBox dynamically

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, filter, datagrid

First to my problem: Id like to filter my `DataGrid` with a `TextBox` dynamically for the `Name`.

My current code:

how the `DataGrid` is filled:

```
cnb1 = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
cnb1.Server = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
cnb1.Database = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
cnb1.UserID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
cnb1.Password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
cn1 = new MySqlConnection(cnb1.ConnectionString);
cn1.Open();
da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM AktuelleDaten", cn1);
da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
hauptübersichtgrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

The Code for the `TextBox`:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataSet DV = ds;
    hauptübersichtgrid.ItemsSource = DV.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Name like '%{0}%'", Filter.Text);
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Just a detail: dont use accentuation on code... read some about variable nomenclature to help create/maintain your projects... also, "translate" some of the names you are adding, because, even if I knew the problem, I could not understand it (and I am Brazzilian, and I even know a bit about deustch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Name like '%{0}%'", Filter.Text);
    hauptübersichtgrid.ItemsSource = dv;
}
```