# How to filter Datagridview using combobox without changing datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I`m making a program using Windows forms and I already built some codes, like this

1. Write a site url in Text Box then click Start Button, matched data showed in DataGridViews.
2. I have a 6 DataGridViews. In First DataGridView, matched data showed(step 1)
   and then, other 5 DataGridviews will showed like cascade refer First DataGridView row`s value(webApplicationName)

code is below

```
private void mtbtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string webApplicationName = string.Empty;
        string siteID = string.Empty;
        mtlblError.Text = "No record returned.";

        Migration_Status_DAC dac = new Migration_Status_DAC();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        //Web Application           
        ds = dac.SelectWebApplicationStatus(mtextUrl.Text);
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        

        if (ds != null && dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            webApplicationName = dt.Rows[0]["AppName"].ToString();
            mgrdWebApplication.DataSource = dt;

            //Content Database
            ds = dac.SelectContentDatabaseStatus(webApplicationName);
            DataTable dtContent = ds.Tables[0];
            if (ds != null && dtContent != null && dtContent.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                mtlblError.Visible = false;
                mgrdContentDatabase.DataSource = dtContent;

                //SiteCollection
                ds = dac.SelectSiteCollectionStatus(webApplicationName);
                DataTable dtSiteCol = ds.Tables[0];
                if (ds != null && dtSiteCol != null && dtSiteCol.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    mgrdSiteCollections.DataSource = dtSiteCol;

                    //Sites
                    ds = dac.SelectSitesStatus(webApplicationName);
                    DataTable dtSites = ds.Tables[0];
                    if (ds != null && dtSites != null && dtSites.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        siteID = dtSites.Rows[0]["SiteID"].ToString();
                        mgrdSites.DataSource = dtSites;

                        //Lists
                        ds = dac.SelectListsStatus(siteID);
                        DataTable dtLists = ds.Tables[0];
                        if (ds != null && dtLists != null && dtLists.Rows.Count > 0) 
                        {
                            mgrdLists.DataSource = dtLists;
                        }
                        //Document Library
                        ds = dac.SelectDocumentLibraryStatus(siteID);
                        DataTable dtDocLib = ds.Tables[0];
                        if (ds != null && dtDocLib != null && dtDocLib.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            mgridDocumentLibrary.DataSource = dtDocLib;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mtlblError.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    mtlblError.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mtlblError.Visible = true;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            mgrdWebApplication.DataSource = null;
            mgrdContentDatabase.DataSource = null;
            mgrdSiteCollections.DataSource = null;
            mgrdSites.DataSource = null;
            mgrdLists.DataSource = null;
            mgridDocumentLibrary.DataSource = null;
        }

    }
```

And Now I want to add this

1. Add Combobox and Add some conditions, for example, [Show all] and [See Over 100GB DB]
2. If I choose [See Over 100GB DB] option, in that DataGridView showed only matched rows.
3. It means, I want to filter Datagridview using Combobox Selection and Datasource is already

   binded, so I want to do not change DataSource....

I try to find combobox and DataGridView, but usually related on Combobox in DataGridView....

And how can I get get first DataGridViews`s value(webApplicationName)

Please somebody help me.. I don`t have any idea...

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter DataGrid for name with TextBox dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34221657/filter-datagrid-for-name-with-textbox-dynamically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a BindingSource to bind your datasource to your DataGridView.
This way you only change the Filter property of your bindingSource and the filter automatically will apply to data shown in the grid.
No need to change datasource.

Comment: Thanks your reply Hassan Eskandari.

Comment: But I used Dataview RowFilter lkie this

Comment: dvLists.RowFilter = string.Format("ListLastModifyDate <= listModifiedDate", mtCbListsSearchConditions.SelectedItem.ToString());

a

Answer (score 0):

I built a code, and works well

1. Use ComboBox SelectedItemChanged event
2. Use DataView and DataView.RowFilter

codes below

```
        private void mtcbContentDBSearchCondition_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataView dvContentDatabase = new DataView(dtContent);

            if (mtcbContentDBSearchCondition.SelectedItem.ToString() == "All")
            {
                mgrdContentDatabase.DataSource = dtContent;
            }
            else
            {
                dvContentDatabase.RowFilter = string.Format("ContentDBSize >= 300000000", mtcbContentDBSearchCondition.SelectedItem.ToString());
                mgrdContentDatabase.DataSource = dvContentDatabase;
            }
        }
```