# How to filter data in DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, filter, datagridview

I am building a windows form application. In this application, I want to use a filter according to a combo box. I have tried some code but it's giving me an exception, **Invalid Column 'drink'**. drink is one of my categories. How can I solve this problem? And I am confused about where I should use the code in the form. combo box method or page load method

```
private void populateCat()
{
    try
    {
        Con.Open();
        string CatValue = CatCb2.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string query = $"select * from ProductTbl where ProdCat={CatValue};";
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, Con);
        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        ProdDGV.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        Con.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter the DataGridView using ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422267/how-to-filter-the-datagridview-using-combobox) & [How to filter datagridview based on combobox selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063159/how-to-filter-datagridview-based-on-combobox-selection) & [How to filter Datagridview using combobox without changing datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913736/how-to-filter-datagridview-using-combobox-without-changing-datasource)

Comment: You should use parameterized query.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Olivier Rogier. But I am still confused about this.

Comment: @ImdadMiran About what? For example on control text changed event handler (or selecteindexchanged for combobox) you put something like: `var ds = DataGridView.DataSource as BindingSource; if ( EditFilter.Text != "" ) { string filter = DefaultFilter.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "" : $"{DefaultFilter} AND"; ds.Filter = $"{filter} Message LIKE '*{EditFilter.Text}*'"; } else ds.Filter = DefaultFilter; DataGridView.ClearSelection();`. Where DefaultFilter is an instance var and Message the DB column name. Are you sure the DB field name is `drink` ? Perhaps `Drink`? Do you need I post this as a detailed answer?

Comment: Thanks @OliverRogier I have caught my problem.

Answer (score 2):

### ISSUE(s):

### Invalid Column 'drink'

The error was when you pass 'drink' value into query.

```
string query = $"select * from ProductTbl where ProdCat={CatValue};";
```

Through the statement above, your SQL query will become

```
select * from ProductTbl where ProdCat=drink
```

Thus you will get this error:

> Invalid Column 'drink'

Suppose your SQL query have to be:

```
select * from ProductTbl where ProdCat='drink'
```

---

### RECOMMENDATIONS

1. Use parameterized query for adding value into parameter(s) and prevent [SQL Injection attack](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection).
2. You don't need a `DataSet`. Seems you are query result from 1 table only. Hence you should use `DataTable`.
3. Would recommend applying "using block/declaration" for `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` to dispose resources and connection when the process ended.

```
private void populateCat()
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(/* Connection string */))
        {
            Con.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from ProductTbl where ProdCat= @ProdCat", Con))
            {
                string catValue = CatCb2.SelectedValue.ToString();
                command.Parameters.Add("@ProdCat", SqlDbType.NVarchar).Value = catValue;

                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    ProdDGV.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Note: This solution is for Post Owner to understand the root cause and how to fix it. To filter DataGridView without the need to fetch from the database, may refer to @OlivierRogier's recommendation on filtering DataGridView.

Answer (score -1):

First go to event of your combo box and in selectindexChange double click then

```
 Con.Open();
        string CatValue = CatCb2.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string query = $"select * from ProductTbl where ProdCat={CatValue};";
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, Con);
        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        ProdDGV.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        Con.Close();
```

Comment: I have done that in a method  and used the method in your recommended place but throwing me an exception.

Comment: @Miad you probably need to add some quotes (or parameters preferably) in the query to make this answer correct