# Filtering an object using Where Clause

Tags: c#, filter, .net-5

I try to filter an object using the clause Where.

My Object is:

```
public class SprGridDisplay
{
    public Int64 SPRNumber { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string SR { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string MinVersionToFix { get; set; }
    public string Technician { get; set; }
    public string Corrector { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public string Qualification { get; set; }
    public string Fixed { get; set; }
    public string Tested { get; set; }
}
```

It' in a DataGridView in which I can filter columns. So I dynamically build a strind containing the filter. For example:

```
listfilter = "(Status != null && ( Status.Contains("3 - Low"))) AND (Version != null && ( Version.Contains("12.0"))) "
```

I have an m_filteredList which is a `list<SprGridDisplay>` and i try to do that

```
m_filteredList = m_filteredList.Where(listfilter).ToList();
```

But it seems that in **.NET 5.0** the parameter for the where clause must be a predicate.

It worked in **.NET Framework 4.6.1** using nuget package **System.Linq.Dynamic**

Any idea about resolving that?

Comment: Have you tried adding https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core

Comment: First try would be to create a predicate. Should not be much more complex than to create a string

Comment: [`.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0) is an extension method located in the `System.Linq` namespace. So probably you can resolve your issues by using the nuget packet if you just remove the namespace include?

Comment: @Jamiec the System.Linq.Dynamic.Core seems to be for  .Net 4.0 not .Net5

Comment: @StéphanF it targets netstandard, you should be able to use it from net5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter the DataGridView using ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422267/how-to-filter-the-datagridview-using-combobox) & [How to filter datagridview based on combobox selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063159/how-to-filter-datagridview-based-on-combobox-selection) & [How to filter Datagridview using combobox without changing datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913736/how-to-filter-datagridview-using-combobox-without-changing-datasource)

Comment: I tried nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core but I cannot make it works to filter a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution :

```
m_filteredList = m_filteredList.AsQueryable().Where(listfilter).ToList();
```